# Passing large matrices to RcppArmadillo function without creating copy (advanced constructors)

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to pass a large matrix to a RcppArmadillo function (about 30,000*30,000) and have the feeling that this passing alone eats up all the performance gains. The question was also raised [here](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2012-July/004037.html) with the suggested to solution to use advanced constructors with the `copy_aux_mem = false` argument. This seems to be a good solution also because I only need to read rows from the matrix without changing anything. I am having problems implementing the solution correctly though. This is probably just a simply syntax question.

Here is my current set-up of the function call (simplified, of course):

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec test(arma::mat M) {
    return(M.row(0))
}
```

this is pretty slow with large a matrix M (e.g. `M=matrix(rnorm(30000*30000), nrow=30000, ncol=30000)`. So I would like to use an advanced constructor as documented [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat). The syntax is `mat(aux_mem*, n_rows, n_cols, copy_aux_mem = true, strict = true)` and `copy_aux_mem` should be set to `false` to 'pass-by-reference'. I just not sure about the syntax in the function definition. How do I use this in `arma::vec test(arma::mat M) {`?

Comment: I am almost certain that this a redundant question here too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has been discussed extensively in the Rcpp mailing list. See this [thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rcpp/5818). The solution that has been implemented in `RcppArmadillo` is to pass the `arma::mat` by reference. Internally this will call the advanced constructor for you.

So with this version, you would do something like this:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec test(const arma::mat& M) {
    // do whatever with M
    ...
}
```

And the data from the R matrix is not copied but rather borrowed. More details in the thread.

Here are some benchmarks comparing the time it takes to copy or pass by reference:

```
                 expr      min        lq    median        uq      max neval
    arma_test_value(m) 3540.369 3554.4105 3572.3305 3592.5795 4168.671   100
      arma_test_ref(m)    4.046    4.3205    4.7770   15.5855   16.671   100
arma_test_const_ref(m)    3.994    4.3660    5.5125   15.7355   34.874   100
```

With these functions:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void arma_test_value( arma::mat x){}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void arma_test_ref( arma::mat& x){}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void arma_test_const_ref( const arma::mat& x){}
```

Comment: The link to the gmane.org thread is dead. It seems that gmane.org itself no longer exists, but has been replaced by gmane.io. Is there a way to view the referenced (ha-ha) thread on gmane.io?

Answer (score 5):

With the CRAN version of `RcppArmadillo`, you would use that sort of syntax:

```
void foo( NumericMatrix x_ ){
    arma::mat M( x_.begin(), x_.nrow(), x_.ncol(), false ) ;
    // do whatever with M
}
```

This has been used in many places, including several articles in the Rcpp gallery.

Comment: It's also been used and discussed in the package itself in the most prominent example, `FastLm.cpp`.