# Trace and inverse of big matrices in R and C++

Tags: c++, r, math, rcpp, armadillo

I need to compute two equations related with trace and inverse of a around 30000 x 30000 density matrices. The equations are

```
-trace( W_i %*% C)
```

and

```
-trace(W_i %*% C %*% W_j C)
```

I know `W_i`, `W_j` and inverse of `C`. These equations are related with Pearson estimating functions. I am trying to use R and package `Matrix`, but I couldn't compute the C matrix, using `solve()` or `chol()` and `chol2inv()`. I do not know with is possible using `solve()` to solve a system of equation and after compute the trace. It is common to use solve function to compute something like `C^{-1} W = solve(C, W)`, but my equation is a little bit different. Any help is welcome. I am thinking about to use RcppArmadillo, but I am not sure that it is able to compute my equations.

Comment: If you could provide an example with small matrices, it would clarify a couple of points about your question and provide a target for developing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RcppArmadillo, but you have to be careful about memory usage. If you save the below code as `arma_test.cpp` it can be sourced via `Rcpp::sourceCpp('w_graph_class.cpp')`. Obviously the matrix data is dummy, but it should give you a starting point. Also check out alternative methods to invert `C` rather than using `.i()`, such as `pinv()`, etc.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866130/passing-large-matrices-to-rcpparmadillo-function-without-creating-copy-advanced)  about large matrices with RcppArmadillo

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List arma_calc() {

arma::mat C_inv = arma::mat(30000,30000,arma::fill::randu);
arma::mat W_i = arma::mat(30000,30000,arma::fill::randu);
arma::mat W_j = arma::mat(30000,30000,arma::fill::randu);

double tr_1=-arma::trace(W_i*C_inv.i());

double tr_2=-arma::trace(W_i*C_inv.i()*W_j*C_inv.i());

return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("Trace1")=tr_1,Rcpp::Named("Trace2")=tr_2);
}
```